# Budget Identifier in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to find a way that I can identify in my Excel sheet when I have an employee that goes over their travel budget the estimated cost I enter for their particular ID number turns red.  I only want it to identify the budget for the ID alone and not the person as people fluctuate.

[image: Budget Tracker]

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide an example of what the expected output will look like in your example?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the cell you want to Conditionally format.
2. Goto **HOME** (tab) | **Styles** (section) | Click **Conditional Formatting**.

For *18b Cost* or *18b Submitted* Cell formatting:

3. Click **Highlight Cell Rules** | **Greater Than**
4. Populate **Format cells that are GREATER THAN:** by clicking the same row's *Estimated Cost* cell.
5. Remove the <kbd>$</kbd> from the row reference so it will be relative.

For *ID* cell formatting:

3. **New Rule...** | **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. Click in the **Format values where this formula is true:** box
5. Click the *Estimated* cell of this *ID* row.
6. Type <kbd><</kbd> (less than symbol).
7. Click either *18b Cost* or *18b Submitted* cell of this *ID* row
8. Remove the <kbd>$</kbd> from both row references so they will be relative.

   - It should look something like this: `=$F2<$G2`